# hot to get every single hour after processing the method

Tags: c#, datetime, textbox

I have 1 method that will run every 1 hour ,,

and I want to make 2 of my datetime textboxes, incrementing 1 hour after doing this method

here's my method:

my textbox name:

- stime_log
- etime_log

```
public DataMngForm(Main Parent)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataMng = Parent;
        Terminal = Parent;
        udisk = new UDisk();
        LoadUDiskFile();
        string ipAdd = txtIP.ToString();

```
    //autoconnect
    int ret = Terminal.SDK.sta_ConnectTCP(Terminal.lbSysOutputInfo, txtIP.Text.Trim(), txtPort.Text.Trim(), txtCommKey1.Text.Trim());

    if (Terminal.SDK.GetConnectState())
    {
        Terminal.SDK.sta_getBiometricType();
    }
    if (ret == 1)
    {
        this.txtIP.ReadOnly = true;
        this.txtPort.ReadOnly = true;
        this.txtCommKey1.ReadOnly = true;

        btnTCPConnect.BackColor = Color.Green;
        btnTCPConnect.Refresh();

    }
    else if (ret == -2)
    {
        btnTCPConnect.BackColor = Color.Maroon;
        btnTCPConnect.Refresh();
        this.txtIP.ReadOnly = false;
        this.txtPort.ReadOnly = false;
        this.txtCommKey1.ReadOnly = false;

        Ping ping1 = new Ping();
        PingReply pingReply1 = ping1.Send(ipAdd);
        if (pingReply1.Status != IPStatus.Success)
        {
            ret = Terminal.SDK.sta_ConnectTCP(Terminal.lbSysOutputInfo, txtIP.Text.Trim(), txtPort.Text.Trim(), txtCommKey1.Text.Trim());
            if (Terminal.SDK.GetConnectState())
            {
                Terminal.SDK.sta_getBiometricType();
            }
        }
    }

    checkBox_timePeriod.Checked = true;

    //calling method "thisTime" every 1 hour
    System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(thisTime);
    aTimer.Interval = 3600000;
    aTimer.AutoReset = true;
    aTimer.Enabled = true;
}
```

//method calling by aTimer
private void thisTime(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
if (checkBox_timePeriod.Checked == true)
{
string fromTime = stime_log.Text.Trim().ToString();
string toTime = etime_log.Text.Trim().ToString();

```
        DataTable dt_periodLog = new DataTable("dt_periodLog");
        gv_Attlog.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        gv_Attlog.Columns.Clear();
        dt_periodLog.Columns.Add("User ID", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
        dt_periodLog.Columns.Add("Verify Date", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
        dt_periodLog.Columns.Add("Verify Type", System.Type.GetType("System.Int32"));
        dt_periodLog.Columns.Add("Verify State", System.Type.GetType("System.Int32"));
        dt_periodLog.Columns.Add("WorkCode", System.Type.GetType("System.Int32"));
        gv_Attlog.DataSource = dt_periodLog;

        DataMng.SDK.sta_readLogByPeriod(DataMng.lbSysOutputInfo, dt_periodLog, fromTime, toTime);

            string MyConnection2 = "datasource=local;Port=3305;Database=sik_gi_new;Uid=root;Pwd=";
            string ip = "192.168.10.19";
            string Query = "insert into dvc0006(NIK,Enroll,deviceIP) value(@NIK,@tgl,@ip)";

            foreach (DataRow r in dt_periodLog.Rows)
            {
                using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(MyConnection2))
                {
                    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(Query, conn))
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NIK", r["User ID"]);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tgl", r["Verify Date"]);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ip", ip);
                        conn.Open();
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    }
                }
            }

    }
}
```

```
please help me
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you share your full source? Do you want to increase datetime text field value by 1 hour? I'm not fully clear your question but you can increase with:

```
DateTime.Now().AddHours(1);
```

if you consider current time. For more details documentation please visit:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=net-5.0

Comment: There is no `.Now()` method.

Comment: Now() is an example. it may be any date object. To set date time text you can use custom date time  formatting. Please check: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

Comment: sorry guys, I have solved my problem and I answered

Answer (score 0):

i added at the las row on my method like this and runing easy :

```
DateTime time1 = Convert.ToDateTime(stime_log.Text).AddHours(1);
                stime_log.Text = time1.ToString();
                DateTime time2 = Convert.ToDateTime(etime_log.Text).AddHours(1);
                etime_log.Text = time2.ToString();
```